# Python: Regex and replace random substring

Tags: python, regex, replace

I need some help with a regular expression in python.

For example:

I have the string:`" "substring 1" + ("substring 2" | "substring 3") "`... with the number of substrings and any operators.

I want to convert this string to: `f (a) + (f (b) | f (c))`

That is, replacing the substring with the function containing the parameter is the string that maintains the order of operators.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Where do `a`, `b` and `c` come from?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: That long string is input. @Alex helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find and replace any substring between 2 quotes:

```
import re
s = ' "substring 1" + ("substring 2" | "substring 3") '

print(re.sub(r'("[^"]*")', r'f(\1)', s))
```